# How to use pandas dataframe column value for multiple if-else conditions to calculate other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

Am having dataframe ,need to implement multiple ifelse conditions to filter `value column` & multiply `expo_value column` with `cal_value  column`

```
Input Dataframe

client_id      expo_value          value          cal_value
1                   126             30                 27.06
2                   135             60                 36.18
3                   144             120                 45
4                   162             30                 54.09
5                   153             90                 63.63
6                   181             120                 72.9
4                   207             30                  99.09
5                   315             90                 126.63
6                   414             120                 81.9

I have written function to filter multiple conditions and apply formula to calculate for that condition

def cal_df(df):
    
    if df[df['value'] <=30]:
        df= df['expo_value'] *30 + df['cal_value'] * 45
        return df
    elif df[(df['value'] <=60 and (df['value'] >=100)]:
        df= df['expo_value'] *60 + df['cal_value'] * 90
        return df
    elif df[(df['value'] <=100 and (df['value'] >=150)]:
        df= df['expo_value'] *100 + df['cal_value'] * 120
        return df
    else df[df['value'] <=10]:
        return np.nan



data = data.groupby('client_id').apply(lambda x:cal_df(x)).reset_index()
results should be stored as new column


### if am applying groupby condition am getting following error

Valueerror: The truth value of a series is ambiguous. Use a.empty ,a.bool(),a.item(),a.any() or a.all()
```

#### if am applying groupby condition am getting following error

#Valueerror: The truth value of a series is ambiguous. Use a.empty ,a.bool(),a.item(),a.any() or a.all()

Comment: use `df.empty` to check if dataframe is empty or not like `if not df[df['value'] <=30].empty`

Comment: @luckyCasualGuy : if i put .empty for all conditions will that work ?

Comment: I dont understand why you want to do `groupby`. From what I can see is your conditions are for columns headers irrespective of `customer_id` and you want the results to be stored as new column in the same (I assume) dataFrame.

Comment: @luckyCasualGuy No actually i just shared sample records but there are more & need to do groupby customer_id & yes i want to save in same dataframe

Comment: is this the dtype of dataframe you are expecting `client_id| int expo_value| int value| int cal_value| int new_column| pd.DataFrame`

Comment: @luckyCasualGuy : Can i apply groupby method for the below function ?

Comment: you can apply groupby after making the new column and result will be the same...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, you don't need to do a groupby. You can do this:

```
data.loc[data['value'] <= 30, "new_column"] = data['expo_value']*30 + data['cal_value']*45

data.loc[(data['value'] <= 60) & (data['value'] >= 100), "new_column"] = data['expo_value']*60 + data['cal_value']*90

data.loc[(data['value'] <= 100) & (data['value'] >= 150), "new_column"] = data['expo_value']*100 + data['cal_value']*120
```

The values for "new_column" in any rows not captured by the above will be NaN by default. But there is another problem, which is those last two lines won't match anything, because something can't be both below 60 and above 100, or below 100 and above 150. Should it be <= for both of them?

Comment: thanks for swift response and sharing code as well i have updated question again why i need groupby condition  thanks

Comment: Can you also add what the resulting dataframe should look like? It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What's confusing me is the two rows with client_id 4 will use your <=30 formula, so one row will be `162*30 + 54.09*45` and the other row will be `207*30 + 99.09*45`. If you use my solution, the first row with client_id 4 will get the result from the first, and the other row will get the result from the second. When using groupby, all rows with the same client_id will get the same result, but it's unclear how you want to calculate that since you aren't combining the multiple expo_value and cal_value from the group in your formula.

Comment: Sure will share output dataframe

Comment: I just added few random numbers but actual logic should be work for <30,<60 & >=100, <=100 & >=150. & groupby should be applied based on 'client_id' at last.

Comment: can you help me with above code how to do group by

Comment: You still haven't provided a better explanation of what you're trying to do or shown what the result should look like. I don't know how to solve your problem using groupby because I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Colin: thanks for sharing , i got it my code is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
def func(value, expo_value, cal_value):
    if value <= 30: return expo_value * 30 + cal_value * 45
    elif value <= 60 and value >= 100: return expo_value * 60 + cal_value * 90
    elif value <= 100 and value >= 150:  return expo_value * 100 + cal_value * 120
    else: return np.nan

df['new_values'] = df[['value', 'expo_value', 'cal_value']].apply(lambda x: func(*x.values.tolist()), axis = 1)
```

Comment: showing error in apply function [typerror: func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given]

Comment: thanks for sharing inputs my code is working now